# Enter scroll mode on pageup or home in tmux

Tags: tmux

I tried to enable home/end keys for a start with this:

```
bind-key -T vi-copy Home history-top
bind-key -T vi-copy End history-bottom
```

with no  success.

I have `set -g mouse on` so scrolling enters scroll mode. I'm looking for the same behavior for home, end, pageup and pagedown.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
bind -n Home copy-mode \; send -X history-top
```